# Capistrano executes a command with sudo although it is turned off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, unix, capistrano

I have the following `deploy.rb` with my capistrano-enabled project:

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.1.0'

# Default value for :pty is false
# forward password prompts
set :pty, true

set :use_sudo, false

namespace :setup do

  desc 'installs required libraries'
  task :libraries do

    on roles(:app), in: :sequence do
      execute :sudo, 'whoami'
      execute :sudo, "apt-get install mplayer"
    end
  end
end
```

I might not really grasp the concept of `:use_sudo` and the `execute :sudo, 'command'` part but curiously the `whoami` returns root, even though `:use_sudo` is turned off.

The [Documentation of v.2](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-from-the-beginning) states this too:

> set :use_sudo, false. By default, Capistrano will try to use sudo to do certain operations (setting up your servers, restarting your application, etc.). If you are on a shared host, sudo might be unavailable to you, or maybe you just want to avoid using sudo.

So what is the `:use_sudo` flag for if sudo is executed anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're explicitly running a command in sudo: `execute :sudo, 'whoami'`, why are you surprised that it uses sudo?

As explained in the documentation that you quoted, setting the `:use_sudo` option to false will tell Capistrano not to use sudo when doing *certain operations*. If you execute `sudo whoami` though it's not going to modify your command.